# Git push failing for GitlabCI Runner

Tags: git, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to implement the Git DMZ workflow: https://gist.github.com/djspiewak/9f2f91085607a4859a66

So I'm trying to write a job that merges from the dmz branch to my master branch.

This is what I came up with:

```
dmz_merge:
    script: 
        - git checkout master
        - git pull
        - git merge origin/dmz --ff
        - git push origin master
    stage: deploy
    only:
        - dmz
```

But when it runs, I get this failure:

```
Checking out 5f7dfe5b as dmz...

$ git checkout master

$ git pull

$ git merge origin/dmz --ff

Updating 005fbd1..5f7dfe5
Fast-forward
 .gitlab-ci.yml | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
$ git push origin master

remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gitlab.mydomain.com/group/project.git/'
ERROR: Build failed: exit status 128
```

Looks like it's not even attempting to use my SSH key, which is where I expected to run into trouble. Is there something else I need to do to get the push to work? I haven't had any luck going through their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to your repository by SSH to use SSH key. Right now you are connecting by HTTP.

Comment: But it looks like GitlabCI doesn't support SSH keys for building: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/README.html

Makes me think there is another solution I should be using.